# having trouble file uploading paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with using the paperclip gem, when i choose my image file and click submit the image file doesn't go through and i have to choose the file image again. So basically i am having trouble uploading images with paperclip gem i need help

#### Command line rails sever

---

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: SET PATH=/usr/local/bin/;%PATH% & file -b --mime "C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Local/Temp/5664a0e0a6a4bd4baf3d5e2cecfcad5520170525-37656-wfezoi.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Mario_(Mario_Kart_Wii).jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

#### new.html.erb

---

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field  :image %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

### message.rb

---

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "700x500>", :small => "350x250>" } ,:default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

### messages_controller.rb

---

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @messages = Message.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @message = current_user.messages.build
  end


  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)

    if @message.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def show   
  end

  def update
    if @message.update(message_params)
      redirect_to message_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit  
  end    

  def destroy
    @message.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description, :image)   
  end

  def find_message
    @message = Message.find(params[:id]) 
  end

end
```